# Trying to enable Firebase for an Existing GCP Project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to enable firebase for one of my gcp projects.
So, i went to firebase console https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/, and when i click on **Add Project** i'm not getting my existing gcp project in the project list.
[image]

Comment: It's supposed to show a little hover window with your eligible Cloud projects. Is that not showing up? Or is it showing up, but not with the project(s) you expect? And is there any relevant error message showing in the JavaScript console, or any relevant failed network requests in the Network tab of the dev tools?

Comment: I'm getting other projects in the dropdown but the newly created one is not showing in that dropdown @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I'm not getting any other errors @FrankvanPuffelen. Just that only one new project is not showing in the dropdown.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think there's supposed to be any delay there, nor is there any filter I know of, so I wonder if it's a caching issue. Can you try in another browser?

Comment: No luck, caching is not the problem. Is it anything related to billing of the project?

Comment: It shouldn't, as Firebase doesn't *require* billing instruments for its projects. Is the project part of a (different) Google Workspace org, and the others are not? I'm honestly just doing troubleshooting here, hoping we stumble upon the cause - but also hope that others have ideas.

Comment: The project is part of different Google workspace org. So, is it the reason i'm not able to see that project?

Comment: I think so, but am honestly no expert at it. I know our support team gets a lot of questions about organizations though, so it might be worth checking with them (and please report back here if you get a solution from them).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233286/discussion-between-raj-kumar-n-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 4):

The reason for GCP project not showing for me in Firebase console is, **Firebase Management API** is enabled before Firebase.
So, i've disabled Firebase Management API and after that i am able to see my gcp project in Firebase console.
Thanks [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) for helping me out.

Before enabling firebase, make sure **Firebase Management API** should be disabled in **GCP API & Services**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue when trying to enable Firebase for an existing GCP project, turns out we had copy/pasted the "firebase: enabled" label in our terraform config.

When we removed this label from the GCP project, the Firebase Console listed the project after a page reload.